# How do i mark that a dictionary<string,object> can have string[] as values with v2 serialization

Tags: azure-service-fabric

```
[DataContract]
public class GatewayServiceRegistrationData : IExtensibleDataObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public Dictionary<string, object> Properties { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, object>();

}
```

Where do i add the known type attribute such string[] is a valid type to put in the dictionary Properties. For service fabric serialization v2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[DataContract]
[KnownTypes(typeof(string[]))]
public class GatewayServiceRegistrationData : IExtensibleDataObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public Dictionary<string, object> Properties { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, object>();

}
```